# Customised IPFS dashboard

Tags: dashboard, ipfs

I have a customised IPFS (created and maintained by someone else). I want to design the dashboard for this customised IPFS Private cluster (like the IPFS desktop for the nodes information). I am researching for Prometheus and Grafana service. What are the ways to achieve this task? I am new to IPFS. Please guide.

Edit: Recently I tried to get IPFS metrics using Prometheus.
http://localhost:5001/debug/metrics/prometheus gives some metric information but not sure it has complete information like peers, files etc info.
Are there any Prometheus exporters for IPFS?  Or how could I use https://docs.ipfs.io/reference/http/api/#getting-started API data for Grafana?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to export custom metrics, but the Prometheus endpoint seems like a reasonable place to start.

Some additional reading:

- https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/pull/6688
- https://github.com/ipfs/go-metrics-prometheus

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you please tell me, http://localhost:5001/debug/metrics/prometheus is used to get the IPFS metrics?

Comment: yup! If go-ipfs is running locally, that page will show a bunch of metrics.

Comment: Instead of writing custom metrics, can you suggest any tool or anything which can help me to create `IPFS` dashboard like the ipfs desktop?

Comment: Or I need guidance to write a custom Prometheus exporter for IPFS.

Comment: If you want to build a custom page, maybe read up on https://github.com/ipfs-shipyard/ipfs-webui

If you want to use grafana, there are lots of examples. Use something like prometheus to gather metrics from go-ipfs and then store them. For example, here is the grafana dashboard Protocol Labs uses: https://github.com/ipfs/infra/issues/399#issuecomment-440533667